# Ubuntu file copy fake success?

Tags: ubuntu, file-transfer, cp

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

When copying a big folder with lots of files and sub folders from my NTFS U disk to my hard drive, the progress bar indicates that copy is finished. But the destination folder size is much smaller than expected.

I turn to use command line, the result is the same.

Any one knows what's wrong with this fake copy success?

Comment: Please provide an example with `ls -al` outputs of both directories.

Comment: @DanielB I tried `ls -al` on the 2 folders. Source folder shows `total 216`, destination folder shows `total 184`. How could it be different?

Comment: That’s what you were asking in the first place. Now please provide the *full output* of both commands, by editing your question.

Comment: That would be too many files... For now, I will try to zip the folder and then copy it as a single file. This is just a workaround.

Comment: So make a minimal example.

Comment: @DanielB Small files seems ok so far. But let me try.